# Call nmap from one container NodeJs

Tags: node.js, docker

compose file:

```
version: '3'
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge

services:

### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
      volumes:
        - './app/:/home/app'
      networks:
        - frontend  

### NMAP ###############################################

    nmap:
      build:
        context: ./nmap
      networks:
        - frontend     
      links:
        - workspace
```

In my first container I have an App in Nodejs and PM2, in the second container Nmap.
In my app, for now I call simply:

```
exec('nmap -A 192.168.1.1/24 oX test.xml', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   .....
 });
```

How can I use nmap that is in second container from my first container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The two containers are isolated from each other.  (Imagine they were two physically separate systems; how would you cause one to run a command on the other?)

If the second program is integral to the operation of the first, you'd need to build a single image and install that tool into the image.

Comment: What about using volume from ? you know something like a portable nmap :D

Comment: Uhm ok, so I have to install all in one image and it is simple, but  then how others container can comunicate beetween them. Such as Laradock with apache, mysql ecc?

Comment: Volumes are for storing _data_, not code, and you can't use them to access arbitrary things in another image.  (`--volumes-from` is probably usually wrong and you should pick a better way to communicate between services if you're looking at it.)

Comment: The various [samples in the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) might be a good starting point for multi-container applications, as would pretty much any [tag:docker-compose] question.